# What's the difference between crontab and cronjob?

Tags: linux, cron

This question may sound incredibly stupid, but if I don't ask I'll never know...

All the tasks setting I do is always by using "crontab". I heard the term "cronjob" somewhere. Is it another tool or just a name for something in "crontab"?

Comment: I was actually looking for an answer for that question. But I know if I do ask it, I'll get -ve votes :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A *cronjob* is just a single entry in a *crontab*, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

The `cronjob` is what you put into your `crontab`.

Answer (score 0):

crontab is the actual command line entry that is used to kick off a cron job (not cronjob).

to create a cron job, do the following

```
 crontab -e
```

And then fill in the cron syntax for the scripts/programs you want to run at a specific "cron'ed" interval.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing in the cron sandbox - lets you try out combinations of crontab timing values and gives you a list of when the job would run. [www.dataphyx.com](http://www.dataphyx.com)